# How to sort bars of a clustered bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written the below code to produce a clustered bar chart. How can I arrange the individual bars from the smallest frequency to the largest frequency?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(y = trans, group = class, fill = class)) + 
      geom_bar(position = position_dodge2())
```

I tried using `fill = forcats::fct_infrq(class)` but it didn't work.

Comment: hello shani, could you include the result of  `dput(mpg)` in your question so the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @mfg3z0 No. The bars need to be arranged for each class category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first count the values per group and create a column that returns the rank number per group. This can be used as a `group` aesthetic to order dodged bars per group like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mpg2 <- mpg %>%
  group_by(trans, class) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(trans) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  mutate(bar_order = row_number()) 

ggplot(mpg2, aes(y = trans, x = n, fill = class, group = bar_order)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>